# Interactive members map

Tags: dictionary, interactive, membership, collaborative

I've been asked to create an interactive map of the members of an academic network working on food and nutrition across the UK.

Ideally, we'd like the members to be able to add themselves onto the map via our WordPress website (adding links to their research profiles, a photo, etc), with minimal admin on our end but moderating abilities.

We'd like to play about with the aesthetic of the map, and would love it to look a bit more interesting than the Google versions!

Does this sound doable, using OpenStreetMap?!

Many thanks in advance for your help,
Murphy

My expertise level is extremely novice, so I've been looking at different open source options, as well as how this might be made from scratch using r or r.Shiny, but I'd love to hear if anyone knows of something similar having been done before!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.